# How to check show grant in inline query using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have inline query of check grant ex.SHOW GRANTS FOR root @'localhost';

I want to pass it as inline query but it doesn't work and throws "Malformed hostname (illegal symbol: '@')

Here is my code:

```
//Username = "root"
//Hostname = "localhost"
//Query: "SHOW GRANTS FOR root @'localhost';"
objConn.InitCommand(CommandType.Text, "SHOW GRANTS FOR @Username @'@Hostname';");
objConn.AddParameter(ref lngErrorNo, ref strErrorMsg, "@Username", MySqlDbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, Username);
objConn.AddParameter(ref lngErrorNo, ref strErrorMsg, "@Hostname", MySqlDbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, Hostname);
if (objConn.ExecuteCommandObjRsReader(ref reader, ref lngErrorNo, ref strErrorMsg) == false)
    blnReturn = false;
```

It throws "Malformed hostname (illegal symbol: '@')" //throw by sql

Can anybody suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Is error thrown in `InitCommand` or `ExecuteCommandObjRsReader`?. MySQL will return an error with a statement like the following: `mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR user@'@ hostname'; // ERROR 1105 (HY000): Malformed hostname (illegal symbol '@')`. @Drew

Answer (score 0):

Despite trying various bindings and searching, I cannot get past the embedded `@` sign in the middle of the command as mysql expects it. The sign messes up the bindings with the other 2 would-be parameters that start with `@` signs.

So, I had to stick with concatenation with no normal bindings with `.Prepare()` and `.AddWithValue()`.

Note, the following is with the .Net MySQL Connector.

Tested, the loop iterates through the rows successfully.

**A word of caution**: use this only as a straw-man until safe bindings can be used with user-supplied data.

```
   public void ShowGrants(string pUsername, string pHostname)
    {   //  
        string sOut;
        using (MySqlConnection lconn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            lconn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {   // drewnow

                cmd.Connection = lconn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SHOW GRANTS FOR '"+pUsername+"'@'"+pHostname+"'";
                using (MySqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rs.Read())
                    {
                        sOut = rs.GetString(0);
                        // do something with it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```